# How to "simulate" a click on a Google Maps Marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, click, handler

What I'd like to do is to invoke the click handler on a marker. So this is my code :

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: location,
    map: map,
    title: title
});    

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    alert("clicked");
});        

marker.click();
```

but I cannot see any alert...

Comment: Check here: http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventListeners

Comment: Already read, but it doesnt explain my request :O

Answer (score 32, accepted):

It's possible to trigger any Maps API event listener on any object using the `google.maps.event.trigger` function.

You'll probably want to pass in a mock `MouseEvent` object, depending on what your event listener(s) do with it.

Example:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(marker, 'click', {
  latLng: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0)
});
```

Comment: Can you give to me an example?

Comment: This doesnt reply to my answer actually :O

Comment: Yes, which is exactly what I gave you. I don't understand what you don't understand. Add the code in my answer to the end of your sample code, and you should see an alert pop up.

Comment: No, it doesn't. It only triggers it on the Marker you pass in as the first argument.

Comment: This solution does not work in clustered markers (one of the group markers) situation. Please share suggestion if you have. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Save your markers in an array. And do something like this:

```
$('#anotherButton').click(function(){
   google.maps.event.trigger(marker[index], 'click');
});
```

Comment: This solution does not work in clustered markers (one of the group markers) situation. Please share suggestion if you have. Thanks.